# Creating bevel effect for content box

Tags: css

I've been working on a CSS3 stylesheet for a program. This is the current look of it: 
[image]

As you can see, I like the design because it's very clean - but one thing that strikes me is that it's very flat.

```
/* REPORT */
.reportBox{
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 20%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.reportBox li{
    list-style:none;
}

.ulReport{
    padding-left:0;
}
```

I want to create more of a separation/contrast between the content and background.
I was wondering how to make the the white square have more of a shadow or emboss effect/bevels look. 
Example:[image]

Could someone help show me an example of it using what I have? I'm assuming I have to mess with the borders and different shades from black to white.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honestly, I like flat UI and a 1px border if it's needed for contrast, but in any case, you can achieve this effect with a double inset `box-shadow` like so:

```
.border {
    box-shadow: inset 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset -0.2em -0.2em 0.2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/96saR/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `border:outset` CSS rule:

```
button{
border:5px outset grey;
}
```

That works well but you have limited control on how the colors look. You can have complete control if you define each color:

```
button{
    border-top:5px solid lightgrey;
    border-bottom:5px solid grey;
    border-left:5px solid lightgrey;
    border-right:5px solid grey;
}
```

Either one works, outset is easier but defining all the colors gives you more control.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/q6Ysk/)